# Tic Tac Toe if no player is a winner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, frontend, boolean-logic

How would I determine if there's a draw? ( begginer coder problems)
I can identify who's the winner but can't seem to figure out how to implement the draw part! please help

heres my code not the prettiest, let me know how I can improve

var player = 1;

```
$('.box').on('click', function(event) {


    alert('add symbol here');
    var boxSelected = $(this);

    $("#goAgain").click(function(event) {
        location.reload();
    });



    if (boxSelected.hasClass('exes') || boxSelected.hasClass('ohs')) {
        alert('Sorry, that has already been taken!');
    } else {
        if (player === 1) {
            boxSelected.addClass('exes');
            if (checkIfPlayerWon('exes')) {
                alert('Congrats! Player ' + player + 'has won the game!');
            } else {
                player = 2;

            }
        } else {
            boxSelected.addClass('ohs');
            if (checkIfPlayerWon('ohs')) {
                alert('Congrats! Player ' + player + 'has won the game!');
            } else {
                player = 1;

            }

        }

    }
});







function checkIfPlayerWon(symbol) {
    if ($('.sq1').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq2').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq3').hasClass(symbol)) {
        return true;

    } else if ($('.sq4').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq5').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq6').hasClass(symbol)) {
        return true;

    } else if ($('.sq7').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq8').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq9').hasClass(symbol)) {
        return true;

    } else if ($('.sq1').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq4').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq7').hasClass(symbol)) {
        return true;

    } else if ($('.sq2').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq5').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq8').hasClass(symbol)) {
        return true;

    } else if ($('.sq3').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq6').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq9').hasClass(symbol)) {
        return true;
    } else if ($('.sq1').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq5').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq9').hasClass(symbol)) {
        return true;
    } else if ($('.sq3').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq5').hasClass(symbol) && $('.sq9').hasClass(symbol)) {
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;



    }
}
```

});

Comment: Check if the game has finished (all squares are taken) but neither player has won.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @Lamar Smith There is one other way I know of, but it is very different from your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class `.square` which all the squares have, then you can run a `forEach` loop over that class like `$(.square).forEach(function(){`..., which checks if the square is empty. If none of the squares are empty then a boolean `game_still_on` would be false and from that, after your syncronous loop has completed you would initiate the draw-game routine.